# Vue3, Typescript and Eslint raise: "Parsing error: '}' expected"

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I am writing code by Vue3 and Typescript, and this is the code of `App.vue`, which is the root component:

```js
<template>
  <router-view v-if="inited" />
  <div v-else>
    Initing...
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import router from './router';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';
import { key } from './store';

const store = useStore(key);

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return { inited: store.state.inited };
  },
});
</script>
```

But the `eslint` tell me:

```
/home/peter/proj/skogkatt-next/src/App.vue
  17:9  error  Parsing error: '}' expected
```

I use many time on Google and so on, but still cannot find a useful solution. This is the config of eslint in `package.json`:

```json
{
  // ...
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "plugins": [
      "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/typescript",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
    },
    "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": "off"
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

I am not sure which config is useful or not, so I post those out. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error is caused by `"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"`, which sets the top-level [`parser`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/682eb7e/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/base.ts#L6), which collides with Vue's `vue-eslint-parser`. In addition, your own config duplicates the top-level `parser` setting already set in the plugin, and should also be removed.

[Vue's ESLint config for TypeScript projects](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-config-typescript/blob/e7e184c/index.js) addresses this problem, so consider copying it:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  // Prerequisite `eslint-plugin-vue`, being extended, sets
  // root property `parser` to `'vue-eslint-parser'`, which, for code parsing,
  // in turn delegates to the parser, specified in `parserOptions.parser`:
  // https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue#what-is-the-use-the-latest-vue-eslint-parser-error
  parserOptions: {
    parser: require.resolve('@typescript-eslint/parser'),
    extraFileExtensions: ['.vue'],
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    }
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended'
  ],
  overrides: [{
    files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
    rules: {
      // The core 'no-unused-vars' rules (in the eslint:recommeded ruleset)
      // does not work with type definitions
      'no-unused-vars': 'off',
    }
  }]
}
```

Another option is to generate a TypeScript project with Vue CLI, and copying the resulting ESLint config.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```js
import { router } from './router';
```

Comment: Sorry but at the `src/router/index.ts`, there is a statement like `export default router;`, so it is not because of this.

Comment: @Crabby its: `import router from './router/index.js';` or `import router from './router/router.js';`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `eslintConfig` specified in both package.json and separate eslint config file. Both of these conflict and give this inconsistent state.

Its best to remove eslintConfig from package.json and move those to eslint config file.